# How to find second max from pandas dataframe (cosine similarity matrix)

Tags: pandas, max, cosine-similarity

How can I find second the second max or max where index!=column from pandas dataframe(cosine similarity matrix)? I could loop through each column and do index!=column but I am sure there is a better way...

```
import pandas as pd
cos = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 1.        ,  0.17404038,  0.36849397],
    [ 0.17404038,  1.        ,  0.20505339],
    [ 0.36849397,  0.20505339,  1.        ]
    ])
cos.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
cos.index = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

cos looks like this

```
    A           B           C
A   1.000000    0.174040    0.368494
B   0.174040    1.000000    0.205053
C   0.368494    0.205053    1.000000
```

Excluding the cells where the values are 1, I want results to be

```
    Col1    Col2
0   A       C
1   B       C
2   C       A
```

Can I do something like this and get the second max in stead of max?

```
results = cos.idxmax().reset_index()
results.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2']

results
    Col1    Col2
0   A       A
1   B       B
2   C       C
```

Comment: Why not just set `1` to `-1` and then get the `max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace `1` with arbitrary value and then call `idxmax` and `reset_index` as before:

```
In [140]:
cos.replace(1,np.NaN).idxmax().reset_index()

Out[140]:
  index  0
0     A  C
1     B  C
2     C  A
```

So just to tart it up a bit:

```
In [141]:
new_df = cos.replace(1,np.NaN).idxmax().reset_index()
new_df.columns=['Col1', 'Col2']
new_df

Out[141]:
  Col1 Col2
0    A    C
1    B    C
2    C    A
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to add the values then you can call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and use the `new_df` values to perform a lookup from `cos` df:

```
In [144]:
new_df['value'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: cos.loc[x['Col1'], x['Col2']], axis=1)
new_df

Out[144]:
  Col1 Col2     value
0    A    C  0.368494
1    B    C  0.205053
2    C    A  0.368494
```

In fact you can use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html#pandas.DataFrame.lookup):

```
In [146]:
new_df['value'] = cos.lookup(new_df['Col1'], new_df['Col2'])
new_df

Out[146]:
  Col1 Col2     value
0    A    C  0.368494
1    B    C  0.205053
2    C    A  0.368494
```

Comment: Ah nice! I did not think about this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry one more question, how would you add a matching value to a new column to new_df? i.e.  I want to see A, C,  0.368494 for the first row

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the rank method to get the rank for all the columns?

```
>>> ranking = cos.rank(ascending=False)
>>> ranking
   A  B  C
A  1  3  2
B  3  1  3
C  2  2  1
```

Comment: Yeah true then I could select all the rows with 2.

Comment: or 3, or 4, or whatever value you need. :) 
plus, it doesn't require you to alter the data...